# overwrite variables or environment values after packaging

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Our goal is to create immutable artifacts and deploy these on different environments.
The Serverless Framework already supports this with the `package` function, so we can build only one build package and deploy it in different environments/AWS accounts.
We create the package with `sls package -v -p build` in our build account/environment and deploy this afterwards in our development, integration and production environments with `sls deploy -v -p build`.

Unfortunately we have not found a way to overwrite environment variables in the different accounts/environments. The used variables and environments are hard coded in the cloudformation-template-update-stack.json after the packaging.

what we tried:

- configuration with external files e.g. `SQS_QUEUE_NAME: ${file(config/config.${self:provider.stage}.json):SQS_QUEUE_NAME}` or `SQS_QUEUE_NAME: ${file(config/config.${opt:stage}.json):SQS_QUEUE_NAME}`
- [serverless-plugin-composed-vars](https://github.com/chris-feist/serverless-plugin-composed-vars)
- overwrite configuration files during deployment e.g. `sls deploy -v -c config/config.production.json -p build`

Have we `missed` anything?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `--stage` flag? To indicate the env?